# adding +1 day to the next date on a join on an incomplete sequence of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores an incomplete sequence dates within the year:

```
eg.
Jan 1
Jan 4
Jan 9
Jan 24
Jan 25
Feb 16
Feb 18
Feb 21
Feb 28
Mar 3
.
.
.
Dec 31
```

I need to do a self join on the table on the dates column. The date needs to join on date a where date b is + 1 day in the sequence. If the dates were complete, I would do a join such as a.date = b.date but instead of `a.date = DATE_ADD(b.date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)`. But I need to it be something like this `a.date = NEXT_DATE_IN_SEQUENCE(b.date)`, but of course this is not a real function, but I am looking for something like this.

Comment: manufacture a row number...

Comment: Can you indicate for a couple of rows what you expect to see as the date in the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a semi-cartesian product:

```
SELECT a.date, MIN(b.date)
FROM dates a
INNER JOIN dates b ON b.date > a.date
GROUP BY a.date;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d279f/1)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.date
        from table t2
        where t2.date > t.date
        order by t2.date
        limit 1
       ) as next_date
from table t;
```